# Using EncryptSymmetric in a Content Block

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, performance, encryption

This is not a question on how to use EncryptSymmetric. I’d like to ask if anyone knows about how well it performs. If we are encrypting a personalised payload that will be added to an outbound link in the html of a Content Block – are there any potential performance risks to consider if the data extension used for the list of emails is very large (sometimes over 1 million subscribers)?

Comment: I don't know it but i would just do a date now before and after the encrypt symmetric function to measure how long it takes and write the timespan to a dataextension with the subscriberkey. After that you could sum the timespans

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick that's a good idea. Will test it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referencing the keys for encryption from key management, I have observed performance issues when sendouts went into the millions. Watch out for that.